# Diagnostic Tools, "Unable to start Standard Collector"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I'm start debugging my Diagnostic Tools are not loading caused by the error "Unable to start Standard Collector". I tried it with an old&new project but I had no success.

I started VS as administrator,

Comment: Does it work if you don't start VS as administrator?

Comment: @MichaelBraude Same problem with VS Admin and VS normal. But now it works with the new Update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed the Update 1 of VS2015 yesterday and it works now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Look at the date of his post. At this time I installed the updates but I doesn't worked

Comment: I don't use VS, I don't know when updates come out either. September isn't that long ago!

Comment: @MartijnPieters VS2015 Update 1 is since one or two weeks out, just that you know now ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025135), it's a known bug that has been fixed. Try installing updates for VS.

Comment: I have the same problem, also tried to install VS update CTP 1 successfully but that didn't solved the problem

Comment: try this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/16/diagnostic-tools-debugger-window-in-visual-studio-2015.aspx